# Cycle through ten items at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my home page of my app I'm looking at displaying a list of ten items at a time. The items after a few seconds will then change to the next ten items in the list and so on.

I have this kind of working however I can only make it work for one item at a time and not ten at a time.

```js
var j = 0;
var inbetween = 2000; //milliseconds   
function page() {
  var jmax = $("ul#list li").length - 1;
  var count = 10;

  $("ul#list li:eq(" + j + ")")
    .animate({
      "opacity": "1"
    }, 400)
    .delay(inbetween)
    .animate({
      "opacity": "0"
    }, 400, function() {
      (j == jmax) ? j = 0: j++;
      page();
    });
};
page();
```

```css
 ul#list {
   width: 200px;
   border: solid;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 200px
 }
 ul#list li {
   font-size: 1.4em;
   padding: 20px;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='list'>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>eliven</li>
  <li>twelve</li>
  <li>thirteen</li>
  <li>fourteen</li>
  <li>fifteen</li>
  <li>sixteen</li>
  <li>seventeen</li>
  <li>eighteen</li>
  <li>ninteen</li>
  <li>twenty</li>
</ul>
```

A jsFiddle to help http://jsfiddle.net/6bbmkujn/

Anything would help!

Comment: j+=n increment j by n

Comment: @Winchestro what is n?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the `position: absolute` is what you're going for. More or less, it seems that you are wanting to select a rotating subset of list items to show at any point in time. I came up with the following changes:

```
ul#list {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid;
  height: 200px
}
ul#list li {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

And the corresponding JavaScript:

```
var j = 1;
var inbetween = 2000; //milliseconds   
function page() {
  var jmax = $("ul#list li").length;
  var count = 10;

  var start = j;
  var end = j + count - 1;
  var complete = 0;
  console.log(j, start, end);

  var range = $('ul#list li:nth-child(n+'+ start + '):nth-child(-n+'+  end +')');
  range
    .show(400)
    .delay(inbetween)
    .hide(400, 'swing', function() {
      if (j++ >= jmax) {
        j = 1;
      }

      if (++complete >= count) {
        page();  
      }
    });
};
page();
```

You can see an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJWpzK

The only real change is that you can see we are selecting a range of elements (based on `j`) using the `nth-child` selector. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! The position absolute was just there for testing purposes while I was playing with things. This is perfect though with just a few tweaks with the timing and display so it's not jumping. :)

Comment: One note I would like to say though is that this is only incramenting at 10 values, so if you have 11 or 15 total items then it breaks.